Invariant Violation and TypeError When Integrating React Native with Existing iOS Swift App
I am currently migrating an iOS app written in Swift to a new React Native project. I successfully integrated a React Native component into my iOS app by first generating a main.jsbundle with the following command:
react-native bundle --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output ios/myApp/main.jsbundle --platform ios --assets-dest iOS

In Swift, I integrated the React Native component using this code:
private func showRNComponent() {
    let rootView = RCTRootView(
        bundleURL: Bundle.main.url(forResource: "main", withExtension: "jsbundle")!,
        moduleName: "DemoPage",
        initialProperties: nil,
        launchOptions: nil
    )
    let vc = UIViewController()
    vc.view = rootView
    self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

This method works fine with the main.jsbundle. However, I attempted to use Metro as a development server for better debugging capabilities and updated the method to fetch the bundle from the development server:
private func showRNComponent() {
    guard let jsCodeLocation = URL(string: "http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios") else {
        NSLog("Invalid URL")
        return
    }
    let rootView = RCTRootView(
        bundleURL: jsCodeLocation,
        moduleName: "DemoPage",
        initialProperties: nil,
        launchOptions: nil
    )
    let vc = UIViewController()
    vc.view = rootView
    self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

After starting Metro and running the development server, when trying to trigger the function, I received the following errors in the XCode console:
Invariant Violation: TurboModuleRegistry.getEnforcing(...): 'DevSettings' could not be found. Verify that a module by this name is registered in the native binary. Bridgeless mode: false. TurboModule interop: false. Modules loaded: {"NativeModules":["PlatformConstants","Timing","AppState","SourceCode","BlobModule","WebSocketModule","SettingsManager"],"TurboModules":[],"NotFound":["NativePerformanceCxx","NativePerformanceObserverCxx","LogBox","DevSettings"]}, js engine: hermes
TypeError: Cannot read property 'render' of undefined, js engine: hermes

I suspect this issue might relate to the XCode build target settings, which should be set to Debug mode to load development settings. Even though I have ensured my build settings and preprocessor macros (preprocessor macros: debug=1) are applied across all build configurations, the problem persists.
Here are excerpts from my Podfile and package.json, detailing the libraries and settings I'm using:
//Poddile
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

require Pod::Executable.execute_command('node', ['-p',
  'require.resolve(
    "react-native/scripts/react_native_pods.rb",
    {paths: [process.argv[1]]},
  )', __dir__]).strip

platform :ios, '14.0'
# min_supported_versions = { :ios => "13.0"}
prepare_react_native_project!

target 'MyApp' do
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  config = use_native_modules!

  use_react_native!(
    :path => config[:reactNativePath],
    :flipper_configuration => FlipperConfiguration.disabled,
    :app_path => "#{Pod::Config.instance.installation_root}/.."
  )

  # Pods for MyApp
  pod 'RxSwift'
  pod 'RxCocoa'
  pod 'SDWebImage'
  pod 'Alamofire'
  pod 'MBProgressHUD'
  pod 'SwiftyJSON'
  pod 'SwiftyUserDefaults'
  pod 'ObjectMapper'
  pod 'Firebase/Crashlytics', '9.2.0'
  pod 'Firebase/Analytics', '9.2.0'
  pod 'Firebase/Messaging', '9.2.0'
  pod 'SwipeCellKit'
  pod 'Kingfisher'
  pod 'WeScan'
  pod 'RxDataSources', '~> 4.0'
  pod 'ChameleonFramework'
#  pod 'FlexLayout'
  pod 'SwiftSoup'
  pod 'IQKeyboardManagerSwift'
  pod 'GoogleMLKit/BarcodeScanning', '2.6.0'
  pod 'MJRefresh'
  pod 'DGCharts'
  
  target 'MyAppTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

  target 'MyAppUITests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end


# post install
post_install do |installer|
  react_native_post_install(
      installer,
      config[:reactNativePath],
      :mac_catalyst_enabled => false
    )
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
      target.build_configurations.each do |config|
        config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '13.0'
      end
    end
  # fix xcode 15 DT_TOOLCHAIN_DIR - remove after fix oficially - https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/12065
  installer.aggregate_targets.each do |target|
    target.xcconfigs.each do |variant, xcconfig|
      xcconfig_path = target.client_root + target.xcconfig_relative_path(variant)
      IO.write(xcconfig_path, IO.read(xcconfig_path).gsub("DT_TOOLCHAIN_DIR", "TOOLCHAIN_DIR"))
    end
  end
  
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      if config.base_configuration_reference.is_a? Xcodeproj::Project::Object::PBXFileReference
        xcconfig_path = config.base_configuration_reference.real_path
        IO.write(xcconfig_path, IO.read(xcconfig_path).gsub("DT_TOOLCHAIN_DIR", "TOOLCHAIN_DIR"))
      end
    end
  end
end
end

{
    "name": "MyApp",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "doctor": "react-native doctor",
        "upgrade": "react-native upgrade",
        "config": "react-native config",
        "android": "react-native run-android",
        "ios": "react-native run-ios --mode \"ETE-t1-Debug\" --scheme=\"MyApp-ETE(t1)\"",
        "lint": "eslint . --ext .js,.jsx,.ts,.tsx",
        "start": "react-native start",
        "bundle:ios": "react-native bundle --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output ios/MyApp/main.jsbundle --platform ios --assets-dest ios",
        "bundle:android": "react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res",
        "clean": "npx react-native-clean-project"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "1.23.1",
        "axios": "^1.6.8",
        "react": "18.2.0",
        "react-native": "0.73.6",
        "react-native-progress": "^5.0.1"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
        "@babel/preset-env": "^7.20.0",
        "@babel/runtime": "^7.20.0",
        "@react-native/babel-preset": "0.73.21",
        "@react-native/eslint-config": "0.73.2",
        "@react-native/metro-config": "0.73.5",
        "@react-native/typescript-config": "0.73.1",
        "@types/react": "^18.2.6",
        "@types/react-test-renderer": "^18.0.0",
        "babel-jest": "^29.6.3",
        "eslint": "^8.19.0",
        "prettier": "2.8.8",
        "react-test-renderer": "18.2.0",
        "typescript": "5.0.4"
    },
    "engines": {
        "node": ">=18"
    }
}

Any suggestions on how to resolve these errors or further steps to debug this issue would be highly appreciated!

Hi Dustin, did you ever figure this out? We're running into the same issue and haven't found a solution yet.

@Rylab If you using custom build configuration. Try add code like this to your podfile:
'ETE-Debug' => :debug,
'ETE-t1-Debug' => :debug,
'ETE-t1-Release' => :release
The cause of this problem is that if you use custom build configurations, they will all be treated as release builds unless you specify them as such.

My problem is solved with adding the custom build config's to the podfile, because my project was using custom build configs.
Sample code is from https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/10015

Thank you @Dustin
